# C++ - Deal with implicit/explicit casts while keeping flexible code

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, explicit

I am looking for a way to express interoperability between a class `A` and built-in integer types while keeping high flexibility in my code. E.g, I would like to be able to use `operator &` freely between (`A` and `A`), (`A` and `int`), (`int` and `A`) and (`int` and `int`), i.e. I want to have the result of `x = y & z` whether `x`, `y` and `z` are type `class A` or type `int`, just writing:

`x = y & z;`

The following code works:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int x;

    explicit A(int i) : x(i) {}

    operator int() {
        return this->x;
    }

    A operator &(const A& src) const {
        return A(this->x & src.x);
    }

};

int main() {
    int b(2), b2(0), b3(0);
    A a(3);

    b2 = a & b;
    b3 = b & a;

    std::cout << b2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << b3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I add a new cast function from `A` to `unsigned int` in `class A`, this does not work any more because `operator &` is defined between (`int` and `int`) and also (`int` and `unsigned int`), so when I do:

`b2 = a & b`

the compiler doesn't know if `a` should be cast to `int` or `unsigned int`, which is logical. I see 2 possibilities to solve it:

1. Explicitely implementing `operator &` between `A` and `int` and between `int` and `A`. I don't want that because adding the compatibility with another type would require to re-implement many combinations of all operators which need to be supported.
2. Forcing implicit conversion from built-in types to `A`, so only `operator &` between `A` and `A` is required.

For flexibility and maintainability, solution 2 is much better I think. So I can implement the following class A instead:

```
class A {
public:
    int x;

    A(int i) : x(i) {}

    A(unsigned int i) : x(i) {}

    explicit operator int() {
        return this->x;
    }

    explicit operator unsigned int() {
        return static_cast<unsigned int>(this->x);
    }

};

A operator &(const A& src1, const A& src2) {
    return A(src1.x & src2.x);
}
```

Now, though conversions from/to int and unsigned int are both defined, I can perform whether (`A` and `A`), (`A` and `int`), (`int` and `A`) and (`int` and `int`).

However I can't compile the code:

```
b2 = a & b;
b3 = b & a;
```

Because as `b2` and `b3` are `int` and (`a` & `b`) (resp. (`b` & `a`)) return a `A` and cast from `A` to `int` must now be explicit, I have to write:

```
b2 = static_cast<int>(a & b);
b3 = static_cast<int>(b & a);
```

My question (finally) is:

Is there a way to code `class A` so I can do:

```
b2 = a & b;
b3 = b & a;
```

while keeping only one definition of `operator &`, between (`A` and `A`)? In theory, that could be done overloading `operator =(const A&)` of class `int`, which is technically impossible.

Comment: I've not found this to be an easy pattern to accomplish in C++.  The other developers using it tend to need to refer to the implementation when they want to use it, and become frustrated with it.  It tends to get labelled "over engineered".  If you are using it for just yourself and your own project, so the idiom works for you, then disregard my comment.

Comment: @bipll Can you please be more precise to help me understand how it can solve my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have just come across a solution. Please consider the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    int x;

    explicit A(int i) :
            x(i) {
    }

    explicit A(unsigned int i) :
            x(i) {
    }

    operator int() {
        return this->x;
    }

    operator unsigned int() {
        return static_cast<unsigned int>(this->x);
    }

};

template<typename T> A operator &(const A& src1, const T& src2) {
    return A(src1.x & src2);
}

template<typename T> A operator &(const T& src1, const A& src2) {
    return A(src1 & src2.x);
}

int main() {
    int b = 2, b2 = 0, b3 = 0;
    A a(3);

    b2 = a & b;
    b3 = b & a;

    std::cout << b2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << b3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It just happens to work. The only problem I see (which is quite important though) is that you can't control the effects of `operator &` with built-in types you have not considered.

New question then:
*Is there a way to restrict my template `operator &` to a given list of types (without template specialization)?*

Answer (score 1):

I think bipll means using free-standing `operator&` functions:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A
{
  int x;
public:
  explicit A(int i) : x{i}
  { }

  explicit A(unsigned i) : x{static_cast<int>(i)}
  { }

  operator int() const
  {
    return this->x;
  }

  operator unsigned() const
  {
    return static_cast<unsigned>(this->x);
  }
};

A operator&(A const& lhs, A const& rhs)
{
  return A(lhs.operator int() & rhs.operator int());
}

A operator&(A const& lhs, int rhs)
{
  return A(lhs.operator int() & rhs);
}

A operator&(int lhs, A const& rhs)
{
  return A(lhs & rhs.operator int());
}

A operator&(A const& lhs, unsigned rhs)
{
  return A(lhs.operator unsigned() & rhs);
}

A operator&(unsigned lhs, A const& rhs)
{
  return A(lhs & rhs.operator unsigned());
}

int main()
{
  auto b = 2;
  auto b2 = 0;
  auto b3 = 0;
  auto u = 2;
  auto u4 = 0u;
  auto u5 = 0u;
  auto a = A{3};

  b2 = a & b;
  b3 = b & a;
  u4 = a & u;
  u5 = u & a;

  cout << b2 << endl;
  cout << b3 << endl;
  cout << u4 << endl;
  cout << u5 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. However, this solution is obvious and discards flexibility brought by implementing only 1 operator &. In my code, I want to support many operators and interoperability with many built-in types, which represents hundreds of operators overloading with this solution.

Comment: Yes, that is the path I've been down too.  That's where the "over engineered" feedback came from.  If you can keep the use cases very narrow, you limit the amount of extra glue functions you need to create.